# I can not find how to eliminate spaces and double character printing in my string modification code

Tags: c

The language is C and the first comment is the desired input -->output
if possible can you let me know the logical mistakes in this and correct it
thank you for helping!

[The Output Currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GujyG.png)

I tried to print a different version of camel case expected the output likewise but got space and double character in it

```
//The aPEs OF naRnia  --> theApesOfNarnia
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100];
    printf("Enter a String \n");
    gets(string);
    int space = 0;
    int i, j;
    int len = strlen(string);
    strlwr(string);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (string[i] == ' ')
        {
            space++;
        
            if (space >= 1)
            {
                string[i] = toupper(string[i + 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    puts(string);
    return 0;
}
```

The current behavior is

```
Enter a String
HEllO woRLD my NmaE is 
helloWworldMmyNnmaeIis
```

The expected behavior:

```
Enter a String
PeNCIL Are MAde Of Lead
pencilAreMadeOfLead
```

Comment: Compiler warning says it all. Function `toupper` is not declared. You need to `#include <ctype.h>`.

Comment: `gets()` is unsafe and no longer part of C. Consider using `fgets()` instead. `strlwr()` is a non-standard function. Consider using `isspace()`.

Comment: `strlen()` returns `size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: @RomanHocke thank you the warning went away but the expected output still does not show i think its a logical error

Comment: Do not put images of text such as compiler diagnostics and program output in your post.  Copy and paste the text itself into the post, and apply appropriate formatting.

Comment: `strlwr()` is a non-standard Microsoft extension, and even MS has deprecated that particular name for it.  I recommend against using it at all, by any name.  I might have suggested writing your own version, but here I think it would be better to integrate the lowercasing directly into the program.

Comment: Can you include what the desired output is supposed to look like.

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714)

Comment: @RudranshPandey Given "to eliminate spaces and double character", do you want input as "HEllO" to have output "HElO"?

Comment: If your teacher/professor is suggesting you use `gets()`, get a new teacher/professor -- that one is doing you no good. `gets()` is so unsafe it had been removed from the C-Standard beginning with C11. (12 years -- more than a decade -- ago...)

Answer (score 1):

> to eliminate spaces and double character

Keep track of the previously saved character and test for same letter with that.

```
    // Untested code
    size_t index_in = 0;
    size_t index_out = 0;
    char ch;
    while ((ch = string[index_in]) != '\0') {
      if (!isspace(ch) && tolower(ch) != tolower(string[index_out])) {
        string[index_out++] = ch;
      }
      index_in++;
    }
    string[index_out] = '\0';
```

- Better code would also access the strings as if they were type: `unsigned char`.
- Do not use `gets()`.  Research `fgets()`.

Comment: I'm afraid this method is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The basic logical error is that when you encounter a space in the input, you replace it with an uppercase version of the subsequent character, but you do not thereby *consume* that subsequent character.  On the next iteration of the loop, it is processed as itself.

You need to ensure that you process each input character exactly once, while handling the likelihood that the result string is shorter than the input.  Among the implications is that you will probably need to move a lot of characters, not just those that appear after spaces.

I am not going to solve your homework problem for you (and if I did, my solution would look very different), but I leave you with one more hint: as you progress through the input character by character, the difference between the input position and its corresponding output position is equal to the number of whitespace characters that have been skipped up to that point. Thus, you could consider something along the lines of `string[i - space] = ...`.